# Switching from full screen to not full screen pop/slide

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

Going from not full screen to full screen with Android works fine. However, upon returning from my full screen activity (a full screen video player), the activity pops in sliding down as the status bar animates down. It seems that the resuming activity is animated in from the full screen mode but with the status bar not there the actual activity is being painted as if it were missing.

I have tried messing with my manifest file specifying themes/styles. I have tried doing this programmatically in onCreate() before the content view is set and various other places in the activity life cycle:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

It seems that there is no way to keep the status bar from animating down and/or from the content view from first drawing without the status bar there and then adjusting down as it is re-shown.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? I am not sure if there is any way to change this and is just a behavior of Android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you resolve your issue? Can you please explain or give some reference?

Comment: I used the accepted answer below by Robert Nekic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a few more flags: FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN and FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS.

Check out http://nubinewsblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/smooth-full-screen-transition.html.

Comment: It's unfortunate the solution requires paddingTop but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void toggleFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
{
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    else
    {
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Use this it will surely work

Answer (score 2):

Following is my solution:

Show the system state bar before finish the full screen Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyFullScreenActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this solution was more useful to me because it didn't cause the original activity to have to adjust its layout padding.

Answer (score 2):

**I've finally found the perfect way to handle this case, without messing with padding.**

You just have to call this line, in the activity which is non-fullscreen :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

This way the layout won't be changed when presenting a fullscreen activity, and you won't see the status bar pop.

Comment: Together with fitsSystemWindows, this solves my problem perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In the root view of the activity layout add

> android:paddingTop="25dp"

In the `onCreate` of the activity, before the `setContentView()` add

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the perfect way to eliminate this problem:

```
private void setFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (fullscreen) {
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    }
    else {
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Call this before `super.onCreate(...)` inside your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this in two steps.

1. Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in my styles for the Activity which I want to show as fullscreen.
2. Use the below code in the Activity's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method
   WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = getWindow().getAttributes();
       attributes.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS; 
       getWindow().setAttributes(attributes);

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you but it worked for me.
Set full screen activity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.my_screen);
```

turn off full screen:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),NewActivity.class));
finish();
```